# MassTransit consumer IContainer payload not set by StructureMapConsumerScopeProvider

Tags: structuremap, masstransit

I'm trying to implement MassTransit middleware for my consumers where I need to grab an instance of an object from the IoC container (using StructureMap), but the container doesn't seem to be set on the payload.

```
public class MyMessageFilter : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class {
  public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { /* Do nothing */ }
  public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
  {
    _logger.Information("IContainer: " + context.TryGetPayload<IContainer>(out var container)); // logs "IContainer: False" where I was expecting it to have been added to the payload
    ...
    await next.Send(context);
  }
}
```

I've configured the following, which I thought would have done the trick. I've confirmed that instances of these classes are being created and used.

```
For(typeof(IConsumerFactory<>)).Use(typeof(ScopeConsumerFactory<>));
For<IConsumerScopeProvider>().Use<StructureMapConsumerScopeProvider>();
```

My configuration of MassTransit looks like this

```
cfg.UseTransaction();
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("some-queue", e => {                        
  e.UseMyMessageFilter();
  e.Consumer<MyConsumer>(container);
});
```

**UPDATE** Changed the code above from e.Consumer(container.GetInstance>) to e.Consumer(container)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built-in configuration methods for StructureMap, as described in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/structuremap.html)? You should just use `e.Consumer(container)` and it will wire everything for you, or use the container registration code and everything is handled.

Comment: Also, if your filter executes prior to the consumer factory, the container won't be added to the payload yet.

Comment: In among trying a couple things, I ended up with the above mentioned code, but I have now reverted the code back to using Consumer<xxx>(ctx) instead (I've made the change in original code posted). 

I'm still not seeing the IContainer payload coming through, and I had suspected what you said about the order was the case, but that's the bit that isn't clear to me; can I change the order or is IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> the wrong filter for me to be creating if I want to manipulate an instance in the container prior to each consumer executing?

Comment: If you register the filter within the consumer configuration, instead of on the receive endpoint, it should have the container instance. That's how you change the order.

Comment: An example configuration observer that adds the filter to the consumer message pipe: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/PipeConfigurators/ConcurrencyLimitConsumerConfigurationObserver.cs#L12